# How to call function of a class in the same class

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to call `get_data` function of class myclass in the same class but it returns this error.

> get_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

How can i call `get_data()` function in the class?

```
class MyClass:
    def get_data(self):
        return(1)
    a = get_data()
ab = MyClass()
print(ab.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of class constructor `__init__`

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        return(1)

ab = MyClass()
print(ab.a)
```

Also, notice I capitalized the class name to follow python classes naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you've made the function a bound method that takes the instance as the first argument but you're not passing any currently.

I'm not sure what you're upto but you can refer the `get_data` method as name `a` (rather than calling), and *call* it after instantiating an instance:

```
In [136]: class myclass: 
     ...:     def get_data(self): 
     ...:         return 1 
     ...:          
     ...:     a = get_data 
     ...:      
     ...: ab = myclass() 
     ...: print(ab.a())                                                                                                                                                                                     
1
```